# Unable to load view on button press iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am unable to load the next view on button press. I have created a button and attached the checkButtonPress action to the button in the IB. But when I press the button on the simulator the next view (ViewOne.xib) do not load. When I tried to debug the code; it is printing the  NSLog(@"View One");written in the if statement below which means the code is reaching to that point but the next view is not loading. I have already created the ViewOne .h, .m .xib files. Following is the code written in  check1ViewController.m implementation file:

```
#import "check1ViewController.h"
#import "ViewOne.h"

@implementation check1ViewController

-(IBAction) checkButtonPress: (id) sender{
    int button = [sender tag];

if(button==1)
{
    NSLog(@"View One");
    ViewOne *tempObj = [[ViewOne alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewOne" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempObj animated:YES];
    [tempObj release];


}
else if(button==2)
{
    NSLog(@"View Two");
}
  }

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the      view is loaded.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
     }
    return self;
 }
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
  }
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 }
*/



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The code is running fine with no errors or warnings.

Any suggestions if I am missing any part in the IB or in the code to be written or do need to override any method in any of the file ... or did I misplace IBAction before any other method

Sorry but I am new to iPhone dev so not sure what I did wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have navigation controller set up properly? check if it is not nil at that place

Comment: I had selected Window-based template while creating the project and the aforementioned -(IBAction) checkButtonPress method is the only code written ... to load the next view expected. Sorry ... just wondering am I missing anything

Answer (score 0):

You application is not having navigation controller so add next view on window for this make object of AppDelegate class and then access window to addView.

```
YourAppDelegate *obj=(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[obj.window addSubView:viewController.view];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But... sorry but I didn't get what you trying to explain as I am still a newbie in iPhone app dev. If possible could you please write a simple app code where you have two views. When the app launches the main view is loaded and on that main view there is one button. when you press the button the next view is loaded. Please suggest how to write this app in window-based template project and using Interface builder and what connections to make in each .xib file in IB to load the next view ... thanks in advance

Comment: Because your application is window based . It is not having navigation controller thats wht you cant use [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempObj animated:YES];
this line.ok but your need to display other view so for this purpose you can add your view on window . Now by default window is a property in appDelegate class.thats why you need to access property of appDelegate class (window) for adding your view on window.so for that purpose use above code. also in your .m class import appDelegate.h file.Ok, try this.

Comment: Thanks for ypur reply. Got it. The problem is sorted by replacing the above code with the following code: 
 if(button==1)
 {
  NSLog(@"View One");
  ViewOne *tempObj = [[ViewOne  alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  [self presentModalViewController:tempObj animated:YES];} Can you please explain what is use of presentModelViewController and how does it work and when to use it. Also what is difference between presentModelViewController and pushViewController. How to decide which and when to use from either of that. Thanks in advance